# I Can't Convert These to Uppercase

Tags: javascript, arrays

In my code i'am trying to test for if the array element is a number and if its a number then set it to itself and go to the next part of the array. If it isnt a number then check if the letter is capital. If its capital set it to the capital value of it in the object and if it isnt keep it at the lowercase value of its object. But now the code wont change it to its object letter or keep them capital. The commented code can translate it to the object component but not keep it at capital. Just please review my code and tell me what I am doing wrong. The point of this is to change the array to the opposite letters(a=z b=y etc.) and also keep its capitalization properties.

```
        function main() {
            var get = document.getElementById("in").value;
            var ina = [...get];
            var script = {
                a: "z",
                b: "y",
                c: "x",
                d: "w",
                e: "v",
                f: "u",
                g: "t",
                h: "s",
                i: "r",
                j: "q",
                k: "p",
                l: "o",
                m: "n",
                n: "m",
                o: "l",
                p: "k",
                q: "j",
                r: "i",
                s: "h",
                t: "g",
                u: "f",
                v: "e",
                w: "d",
                x: "c",
                y: "b",
                z: "a",
                " ": " "
            };
            for(i = 0; i < ina.length; i++) {
                var x = isNaN(ina[i]);
                var y = ina[i];
                if(x) {
                    if(y == y.toUpperCase()) {
                        y = script[y];
                        y = y.toUpperCase();
                    } else {
                        y = script[y];
                    };
                } else {
                    y = script[y];
                };
            };
            var outa = ina.join("");
            document.getElementById("out").value = outa;

    };
        /* for(i = 0; i < ina.length; i++) {
                ina[i] = script[ina[i] || ina[i]];
            };

            var outa = ina.join("");
            document.getElementById("out").value = outa;

        };
        */
```

Comment: You call `y = y.toUpperCase();` in exactly the branch where you have tested that `y` already is uppercase

Comment: You never modify anything in `ina`. The only variables you assign to are `x`  and `y` and their values are lost at each new  iteration. So the whole `for` loop serves no purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should assign `y` to `ina[i]` at some point, which currently is not happening. Furthermore you apply `y.toUpperCase()` when `y` is already upper case.

I would also suggest to drop the `isNaN` test. It seems better to test whether the character has a translation in `script`, and if not, to leave the character unchanged.

Here is the suggested loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < ina.length; i++) {
    var y = script[ina[i].toLowerCase()] || ina[i];
    if (ina[i] == ina[i].toUpperCase()) y = y.toUpperCase();
    ina[i] = y;
}
```

Comment: If you test by checking whether it doesn't change when invoking `toUpperCase`, you can omit the test completely :-)

Comment: Ah, I got confused. This was only a problem in the OP's script, which had `var y = ina[i];`

Answer (score 0):

You keep setting the temporary variable `y` to the letter you want, when you should be setting `ina[i]`. Try this:

```
                if(y == y.toUpperCase()) {
                    ina[i] = script[y].toUpperCase();
                } else {
                    ina[i] = script[y];
                };
```